# Error with HoltWinters from a TS "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ"

Tags: r, holtwinters

I'm converting a ts object into a HoltWinters prediction. My data looks like this:

```
TP  Year    Day Temp
1     1996  1     98
2     1996  2     97
3     1996  3     97
4     1996  4     90
```

And my code looks like this:

```
temps <- read.delim("temps2.txt")

ts <- ts(temps, start=c(1996,1), frequency = 123)

plot(ts, main="raw ts")

hw <- HoltWinters(ts, beta = FALSE, gamma = TRUE)

plot(hw)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

But the confusing thing to me is I know I want my x to be **time** and my y to be the values from the **Temp** column, but I didn't ever tell that to hw, so I don't know how to fix it. Once I get the hw object created correctly I want to make a exponential smoothing prediction for the future.

Suggestions welcome:) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It worked as soon as I gave the temp to the ts object like this:

```
ts <- ts(temps$Temp, start=1996, frequency = 123)
```